# stm32f2xx HSI configuration does not work correctly

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, clock, stm32, pll

I'm using below settings (in `SystemInit` function) to configure a STM32F215RG MCU to work at maximum speed (120MHZ) with USB support:

```
    RCC_DeInit();
    RCC_HSICmd(ENABLE);
    while(RCC_GetFlagStatus(RCC_FLAG_HSIRDY) == RESET);

    /* Flash 3 wait state, prefetch buffer and cache ON */
    FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_3);
    FLASH_PrefetchBufferCmd(ENABLE);
    FLASH_InstructionCacheCmd(ENABLE);
    FLASH_DataCacheCmd(ENABLE);

    /* HCLK = SYSCLK */
    RCC_HCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLK_Div1);
    /* PCLK2 = HCLK/2 */
    RCC_PCLK2Config(RCC_HCLK_Div2);
    /* PCLK1 = HCLK/4 */
    RCC_PCLK1Config(RCC_HCLK_Div4);
    /* Configure the main PLL clock to 120 MHz */
    RCC_PLLConfig(RCC_PLLSource_HSI, PLL_M, PLL_N, PLL_P, PLL_Q);
    /* Enable the main PLL */
    RCC_PLLCmd(ENABLE);
    /* Wait till the main PLL is ready */
    while(RCC_GetFlagStatus(RCC_FLAG_PLLRDY) == RESET);

    /* Select the main PLL as system clock source */
    RCC_SYSCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLKSource_PLLCLK);

    /* Wait till the main PLL is used as system clock source */
    while (RCC_GetFlagStatus(RCC_FLAG_PLLRDY) == RESET);
```

& here are PLL config params:

```
#define PLL_M      16
#define PLL_N      240

#define PLL_P      2
#define PLL_Q      5
```

But seems there is a problem with HSI because MCU does NOT start to work after restarting.
But when I configure it to use HSE instead (with 8MHZ crystal, `PLL_M=8`) the MCU works as expected.
Is there any mistake in my configuration?

Comment: Can you get it to run off the HSI at any frequency at all - such as directly, or with a lower PLL factor, leading to maybe 48 or 72 MHz?  Also, what is means you are using to discover that it is not working?  If it's something like the SWD debugger or waiting for a GPIO to toggle, that's sound - if you are waiting for it to talk on USB or even serial, your problem might be in configuring that communication peripheral for this clock rate, rather than actually getting the CPU to run at it.

Comment: No, I've tested on other frequencies & it does NOT work with lower PLL factors. For testing I'm using GPIO with a simple blinking LED sample!